# Two actions in one button(image changing)

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a problem to assign two actions to one button. After clicking the image, image changes. Action only works when I click on image, not on a button. Can you have any ideas how to change code that after clicking the button image change and action happens?

Here is my code:

```
  <a href="" class="btn btn-gray">
                <img src="images/icons/full.png" alt="" ng-click="candidates.setTableType(candidates.tableTypes.ADVANCED)"
                     ng-show="candidates.selectedTableType == candidates.tableTypes.SIMPLE">
                <img src="images/icons/full-hide.png" alt="" ng-click="candidates.setTableType(candidates.tableTypes.SIMPLE)"
                     ng-show="candidates.selectedTableType == candidates.tableTypes.ADVANCED">
            </a>
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: can you use simple jQuery here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `<a>` here and move your `ng-click` and `ng-show` attributes to respective links.

```
 <a href="" class="btn btn-gray" ng-show="candidates.selectedTableType == candidates.tableTypes.SIMPLE" ng-click="candidates.setTableType(candidates.tableTypes.ADVANCED)">
    <img src="images/icons/full.png" alt="">
</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-gray" ng-click="candidates.setTableType(candidates.tableTypes.SIMPLE)" ng-show="candidates.selectedTableType == candidates.tableTypes.ADVANCED">
    <img src="images/icons/full-hide.png" alt="" >
</a>
```

Comment: It works almost fine but, after clicking the button, another button disappearing after a moment( it's  showing up next to another for a moment)

Comment: @urqel Well, this is something related to the performance of `AngularJS` in your browser, I'm not sure how can we minimize this effect.

Comment: @urqel One possible hack I can tell you is wrap both buttons in a `div` with `height` equal to button height and  place buttons with `position: absolute` with `top: 0` and `left: 0`. In this way both will appear on above another and you will not see this effect.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just sill learning CSS/HTML, but i could solve your problem with a bit of javascript.  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/eTniez/3gz7pmck/1/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="btn" id="myDiv" onClick="bgcol()"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">LINK</a> </div>
```

**JS Code**

```
 <script> function bgcol()
{ 
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://dataduppedings.no/subcube/Colour_Gradients/Cyan-Blue_256x256.png')"; 
 /* insert your image here */ 
} </script>
```